# How to copy an array to extended array?

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, .net

I have defined my extended class this way:

```
public class ExtendedAttributeMetadata : AttributeMetadata
{
    public bool IsTwoOption { get; set; }
}
```

But upon copying the source array of type `AttributeMetadata[]` to my new destination array `ExtendedAttributeMetadata[]`, i am getting `InvalidCastException`:

> *"At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type."*

Code:

```
AttributeMetadata[] attributes;
//...
ExtendedAttributeMetadata[] extendedAttributes = new ExtendedAttributeMetadata[attributes.Length];                
attributes.CopyTo(extendedAttributes, 0);
```

**ADDED:**

Where `AttributeMetadata` is derived from MetadataBase

```
public class AttributeMetadata : MetadataBase
```

And `MetadataBase` is an abstract class.

```
public abstract class MetadataBase : IExtensibleDataObject
```

Please suggest the best and optimal way of copying in my case.

Comment: Where did the original array come from? It seems pretty clear that at least one of the elements of the original array is not of type `ExtendedAttribute`.

Comment: Original array is of type Attribute[] from which i have extended my class.

Comment: Your edits don't change anything: you're trying to copy an object that is *not* of type `ExtendedAttributeMetadata` into an array of type `ExtendedAttributeMetadata`. That just isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could not copy a base class to derived class so you must be generate it:

```
var extendedAttributes = 
   attributes.Select(p=>new ExtendedAttribute{IsTwoOption=true/false}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the list of attributes just the `AttributeMetadata` abstract base class?

You are getting that error because there are Attributes in the list that are not of type `ExtendedAttributeMetadata`

you can filter these out with a linq statement:

```
var extendedAttributes = attributes.OfType<ExtendedAttributeMetadata>().ToArray();
```

Comment: the OfType<> filter should still work if you replace ExtendedAttribute with ExtendedAttributeMetadata.